# Post request to Jersey from Laravel

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I have a simple REST API created with Jersey on Glassfish server.

On the other hand, I have a Laravel application that uses this API. Now, I have several GET routes on Jersey app, and this works with no problem. I used it with `curl` and everything went well.

At the end, I have one post request that I should send. Form consists of about 50 fields, and I'm not sure how to triger it.

When I put the url to post method into form `action` attribute, I get this message

```
HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type
```

I have tried with

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
```

And with

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

And I get the same error with both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this but it, but be sure to include the form parameters in the method signature

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void post(@FormParam("name") String name) {
// Store the message
}
```

as described [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html)